# Pass function name as argument when running bash script

Tags: bash

Assuming I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hello (){
    echo hello,
}

function world (){
    echo world!
}
```

Is it possible to select the functions to run while I start the script?
For exmaple:

```
./test.sh hello world
```

output:

```
hello,world!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over the arguments and run them.

```
for i in "$@"; do
    "$i"
done
```

Do not use `function name()`, just `name()`. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete . Check your scripts with shellcheck .

Comment: That about covers it all -- you left nothing to add...

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **eval** command to execute first argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

function hello (){
    echo hello,
}

function world (){
    echo world!
}

eval $1
```